# Sending meeting request to more than one email using c# code

Tags: c#, outlook

i wrote a function using c# , that is sending a meeting request to an email address .

i want to modify this function just to be able to send the meeting request to more to more than one Recipients .

where should i set the code that is responsible for this , down here is my code that implements this

```
 string startTime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
            string endTime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(endTime).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(mailfrom, emailto);

            msg.Subject = Subject;
            msg.Body = emailbody;

            #region Calender Request
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");

            //PRODID: identifier for the product that created the Calendar object
            str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//test //Outlook MIMEDIR//EN");
            str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");

            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", startTime1));//TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc("BeginTime").ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", endTime1));//TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc("EndTime").ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("LOCATION: {0}", "Location"));

            // UID should be unique.
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));

            str.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
            str.AppendLine("ACTION:Accept");
            str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
            str.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY");
            str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

            str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
            System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
            ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
            ct.Parameters.Add("name", "meeting.ics");
            AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), ct);
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
            #endregion

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.outlook.com", 587);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("lma@test.com", "test1234");
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BCC or CC property

```
MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress("manager1@contoso.com");
msg.Bcc.Add(bcc);
```

You can add as many Recipients as you want

[Bcc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Cc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.cc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can have only one "to" property.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If you use Bcc every Recipient will get their own copy of email

Comment: ,,,, thanks very much for you fast response . ii have tried to use msg.To.Add(to); for more than one address and it worked successfully . but your answer enlighten the way for me :)

Comment: ,,,, do u have any idea if it is possible to request a response for the meeting request from the Recipients ,,, as my current code just send the meeting appointment and doesn't request a response for it

Comment: @Laila the above method will not work as expected.. it wont give you the rsvp response

Comment: @Downvoter, why did you downvote this answer? It answers the question with well-structured and well-explained code. If you disagree with the question then downvote/flag the question, but do not downvote answers - judge them on their own merit.

Comment: @Laila what do you mean by "response for the meeting request from the Recipients". Do you need a RSVP?

Answer (score 1):

You can send many more with BCC or CC property

```
MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress("manager1@contoso.com");
msg.Bcc.Add(bcc);
```

The above two lines of code will just send the appointment(.ics) items, but it won't give the rsvp response back to the organizer. Also it will hide the `Response` options!!!

So you need to have the attendees set as like below code :

```
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, "manager1@contoso.com"));   //Attendee 1
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, "manager2@contoso.com"));   // Attendee 2
```